# Where to find (or how to read) ruby documentation?

Tags: ruby, documentation

Running through some examples about sockets, one I've come across is this one and I'm struggling with the syntax a bit. Here's the code, it works just fine;

```
require "socket"

server = TCPServer.new(1234)

loop do
  Thread.start(server.accept) do
    |connection|
    puts "Connection started"
    while line = connection.gets
      break if line =~ /quit/ 
      puts line
      connection.puts "received"
    end

    conneciton.puts "closing the connection"
    connection.close
  end    
end
```

After a little head scratching I figured out that the server.accept code would wait until a connection is detected before starting a thread that loops until quit is called, then closes it.

What I would like a little help with is how I was supposed to have inferred this from the documentation without noodling around with the code? Am I looking in the wrong place for documentation or is it there in plain sight and I'm just not reading it correctly? Here's the source I've been using;

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/socket/rdoc/TCPServer.html#method-i-accept

Comment: That is the official location for source. The Internet and books written by experienced developers are a good additional source of tutorials and documentation on both trivial and non-trivial concepts.

Comment: The code highlighting seems to be a bit borked in that `TCPServer.open(“127.0.0.1”, 14641) {|serv|` lacks a grey background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The truth is, that documentation could be better.

That documentation assumes you're familiar with sockets already—that's a very similar (maybe even identical) behavior to the POSIX [accept](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/accept.html) call, whose documentation states that if they're aren't pending connections and you didn't explicitly request non-blocking operation "accept() shall block until a connection is present". ("Block" is UNIX-speak for a particular type of waiting).

Non-blocking operation in the Ruby class is `accept_nonblock` (according to the document you linked), so you can infer `accept` is blocking.

The Ruby documentation is maintained by volunteers, and I'm sure they'd be happy to accept patches to make it better.